# Extend the evaluation version of Visual Studio

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

My current customer hasn't provide me licence for the moment and I alreayd used the 90 day trial. I just want to extedn it for one day in order to put my code on TFS, how can I?

I'm under VS 2013 Ultimate

Thanks in advance

Comment: I finally install Pro version, get 90 days back, I put my code on TFS then use code.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `Visual Studio 2013 Community Edition`

> Visual Studio Community 2013 is a new edition that enables you to unleash the full power of Visual Studio to develop cross-platform solutions.

It is a free full-featured IDE that will allow you to continue your work.

http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/vs2013-community-vs.aspx